# How can Windows Firewall be used to further increase security in Windows 10, would it be by blocking particular ports?

Tags: windows-10, security, firewall, port, windows-firewall

How can Windows Firewall be used beyond it being turned on, to increase security of a Windows 10 Home PC, would it be best to use the firewall to block these ports?
I would like it to be as secure as reasonably possible.

Many sites suggest blocking / disabling these:

- Port 139
- Port 445
- Port 3389
- NetBIOS
- SMB (have already turned off SMB1 in Windows Features)

Some sites mention blocking these also:

- Port 135
- Ports 137 & 138
- Port 1433
- Port 1434
- Port 3306
- Port 33060

What effect, in everyday usage, would blocking all the above have on the machine?

E.g. I've seen that Ports 139 & 445 are called dangerous by some websites, but are used for things like Event log, print spooler, Performance logs.
ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/service-overview-and-network-port-requirements

About the machine:

- Windows 10 Home
- Software: Windows Defender, Malwarebytes, LibreOffice, photo / drawing software.
- Will be used for: emails (via website not email program), a few websites, uploading photos.
- Will not be used for: internet meeting software, file sharing, remote desktop, gaming, printing via a network, grouping or sync with other devices, wireless.

Thank you

Comment: Samba/SMB/NetBIOS ports [`137:139` and `445`] are not "dangerous" ports on an endpoint not directly exposed to WAN _(e.g. NAT'd behind a router with a stateful firewall)_, they're required for network shares _(SMBv1 is actively exploited, whereas SMBv2+ is not)_. The main reason to firewall outbound traffic in Windows would be to limit data and telemetrics being shared with the developer, and requires knowing precisely what source ports an arbitrary application uses and what it uses those ports for _(this route will result in more frequent network issues that need to be troubleshooted)_

Comment: Are there other computers on your LAN?

Comment: @JW0914 Thank you for your informative comments. About network shares, do you mean literally sharing files with other computers on a LAN network? I won't be sharing files between PCs. The main reason I would want to restrict outbound traffic would be to attempt to curtail the effect of some types of malicious activity, e.g. the NetBIOS worms mentioned in some articles.

Comment: Thank you @Frank for your question, there will be other PC's on the LAN but they will all be set to 'Public' connection, and not be able to share files, etc. I would like to keep them as separate as can be possible on the same LAN.

Comment: in that case, the impact of making those changes will be negligible, both in terms of impact to your use, but as others have pointed out, won;t really make your network more secure, unless you already have an active threat actor within your network perimeter.

Answer (score 1):

The articles you have read probably list ports that should not be
lightly opened for inbound connections.

By default Windows Firewall blocks **all** incoming connections,
so there are no ports to close - all are closed.

All outbound ports are open, but there is no point in closing ports
that are used by your installed applications.

I suggest, before modifying any settings, to well understand the concepts.
In the meantime, keep the defaults as they are.
Windows Firewall defaults are pretty secure.

One of the many articles that you can find and read on the internet:
[Best practices for configuring Windows Defender Firewall](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/best-practices-configuring).

Comment: Thanks, the articles mentioned worms etc & blocking in/outbound. EG https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/preventing-smb-traffic-from-lateral-connections-and-entering-or-leaving-the-network-c0541db7-2244-0dce-18fd-14a3ddeb282a https://www.thewindowsclub.com/smb-port-what-is-port-445-port-139-used-for I read incoming ports are blocked by default, but superseded by wide allow rules, specific allow, then block (I believe). Is blocking ports belt-and-braces? How can you tell if the router uses DHCP for IP's, or if DHCP's blocked? Thanks for the link & confirming defaults are pretty secure.

Comment: You can go into the router's admin pages and check the firewall, but it should be the same as for Windows, with all inbound ports closed by default. You could even check the ports using an external website such as [ShieldsUP!](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2). The warning articles you have read are for people that open ports in their firewall, which is likely not your case. If you don't change the defaults, you are quite safe, as long as you don't click on funny links or install bad software.

Comment: Thank you, I shall look at the router. I read some routers use DHCP to send IP's to devices, is this common? Would it say something obvious if it did? I don't open ports you are right. However, I'm aware that software sometimes opens ports on installation, and well meaning designers could create rules that include opening ports I don't want open. There are a lot of firewall entries with the port listed as Any, should that be a concern? I would consider myself strict with what I click on or install.